Does catechol give Tollens’ test?
Do hydroquinones like catechol or p-hydroxyphenol give Tollens’ test?
I know that β-diketones can reduce Tollens’ reagent to give a “silver mirror”, so I would guess that due to tautomerization catechol can form its enolic form which is a β-diketone:

But still it would be helpful if I could get a better reasoning and mechanism.

No, hydroquinones do not give Tollen's test.
The Tollens' test is a qualitative test that distinguishes between aldehydes and ketones. It is based on the ability of aldehydes to convert silver ion (Ag+) to metallic silver (Ag) in Tollens' reagent (a solution of silver nitrate (AgNO3) and ammonia (NH3). On the contrary, hydroquinones are not aldehydes. Since they have two hydroxyl (OH) groups joined to an aromatic ring, they are categorised as diphenols. They react differently from aldehydes with Tollens' reagent, despite the fact that they can experience oxidation reactions.

But I was asked in a test to count the number of compounds that would give silver mirror with tollens reagent and in the answer key Catechol was also counted
